# Change size and aspect ratio without distortion

Tags: r, image-processing, magick-r-package

i'm searching for a way in R to make 400x400px images (.jpg/.png) out of a larger images of different size and aspect size without distorting it. The new image should have most of the content of the original one but can be cut off a bit on the left and right so that it becomes a square without distortion.

How far I got (with distortion):

```
library(magick)

pics <- list.files("./")

for(i in 1:length(pics)){

  a <- image_read((paste0("./", pics[i], sep="")))

  b<-image_resize(a, "300x300!")

  image_write(b, path = paste0("./", pics[i], sep=""), format = "jpg")
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Dominik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these lines right before the resize line `b<-image_resize(a, "300x300!")` to crop `a` so it is square.

```
newdim <- min(image_info(a)[c('width', 'height')])
a <- image_crop(a, geometry = geometry_area(newdim, newdim))
```

Comment: nice, that's it! Thanks a lot!